# Drag and Resize the textbox via SVG circles - Javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to drag and resize this textbox via help of `svg` circle which is appended around on textbox, of `onclick` on append button.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->
<html>
<head>
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    function appendExternalGrid(){
        debugger;
        var width = $('#fName')[0].offsetWidth;
        var height= $('#fName')[0].offsetHeight;
        var top= $('#fName')[0].offsetTop;
        var left= $('#fName')[0].offsetLeft;
        var d = 'M'+0+','+0+' '+'L'+width+','+0+' '+width+','+height+' '+0+','+height+' '+'z';
        var  element =  '<svg  id = "svgBox" style="position:absolute;top:'+(top-1)+'px;left:'+(left-1)+'px;height:'+height+'px;width:'+width+'px; ">'; 
        element += '<path id="selectedBox0" fill="none" stroke="#22C" stroke-dasharray="5,5" d="'+d+'"></path>';
    element += '<circle id="selectorGrip_resize_nw" fill="#22C" r="4"   stroke-width="2" cx="'+0+'" cy="'+0+'"></circle>';
        element += '<circle id="selectorGrip_resize_n" fill="#22C" r="4"   stroke-width="2"  cx="'+(width/2)+'" cy="'+0+'"></circle>';
        element += '<circle id="selectorGrip_resize_ne" fill="#22C" r="4"   stroke-width="2"  cx="'+width+'" cy="'+0+'"></circle>';
        element += '<circle id="selectorGrip_resize_e" fill="#22C" r="4"   stroke-width="2"  cx="'+width+'" cy="'+(height/2)+'"></circle>';
        element += '<circle id="selectorGrip_resize_se"  fill="#22C" r="4"  stroke-width="2"  cx="'+width+'" cy="'+height+'"></circle>';
        element += '<circle id="selectorGrip_resize_s" fill="#22C" r="4"  stroke-width="2" cx="'+(width/2)+'" cy="'+height+'"></circle>';
        element += '<circle id="selectorGrip_resize_sw" fill="#22C" r="4"  stroke-width="2"  cx="'+0+'" cy="'+height+'"></circle>';
        element += '<circle id="selectorGrip_resize_w" fill="#22C" r="4"  stroke-width="2"  cx="'+0+'" cy="'+(height/2)+'"></circle>';
        element += '</svg>';
        $('#fName')[0].style.position='';
        $('body').append(element);
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectorGrip_resize_se" ).resizable();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" style="width:256px" id='fName' name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" value=""><br><br><br><br><br>
    <input type="button" onClick="appendExternalGrid();" id='append'  name="btn" value="append">
    <input type="button"  id='remove' name="btn" value="remove">
</body>
</html>
```